# Eigenvalue of product of two singular matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, rotations, spectral-theory

Let $\theta>0$, and for all $k\in\mathbb{N}$, define $f_k\triangleq \begin{bmatrix}\cos k\theta\\\sin k\theta\end{bmatrix}\in\mathbb{R}^2$. Show that for all $k\in\mathbb{N}$, 
$${\rm spec}\big((I_2-f_kf_{k}^{\rm T})(I_2-f_{k+1}f_{k+1}^{\rm T})\big)=\{\lambda_1,0\}, \qquad {\rm where}\qquad |\lambda_1|<1$$

---

What I know sofar:

Note that 
$$f_{k+1}=Rf_k,\qquad {\rm where}\quad R\triangleq\begin{bmatrix}\cos\theta&-\sin\theta\\\sin\theta&\cos\theta\end{bmatrix}. $$

Also note that for all $k\in\mathbb{N}$,
$${\rm spec~}(I_2-f_kf_{k}^{\rm T})=\{1,0\}.$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Brute force computation shows that
$$(I_2-f_kf_k^T)(I_2-f_{k+1}f_{k+1}^T)=\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 \cos (\theta ) \sin (k \theta ) \sin ((k+1) \theta ) & -\cos (\theta ) \cos ((k+1) \theta ) \sin (k \theta ) \\
 -\cos (\theta ) \cos (k \theta ) \sin ((k+1) \theta ) & \cos (\theta ) \cos (k \theta ) \cos ((k+1) \theta ) \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

The characteristic equation is
$$Det((I_2-f_kf_k^T)(I_2-f_{k+1}f_{k+1}^T)-\lambda I_2)=\frac{1}{2} \lambda  (-\cos (2 \theta )+2 \lambda -1)$$
This gives
$$\lambda =\frac{1}{2} (\cos (2 \theta  k-2 \theta  (k+1))+1)$$

Comment: Thanks. I forgot to mention that I don't want to use brute force. Can you think of any other approach?